# .setValue of an Element/Hidden Element

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, spreadsheet

```
function change(e){
var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();  
app.getElementById("date").setValue(e.parameter.picker);  
Browser.msgBox(e.parameter.date+"|"+e.parameter.picker);  
return app;  
}
```

I've spent the last hour or so trying to figure out what I am doing wrong, but, the .setValue() seems to not be working, since the Browser.msgBox displays: " | August 8, 2012 0:00:00 (MST)" even though both sides from the | should display the same thing.

Comment: You should be more specific with your tags.  By the looks of it, this is Google apps script?

Comment: Yea, It is Google Apps Script, sorry.. Thought I added that.

Comment: Thanks. I swear I didn't see google-apps-script as a tag

Answer (score 0):

The right way to assign a value to a widget in a handler function in GAS is simply (just as you did in your question) like this :

```
app.getElementById("date").setValue(e.parameter.picker)
```

but what follows in your code can't work because **value is passed to the e.parameter when the handler function is called**, not during execution of the handler.
This means that `e` is not updated inside the handler function but it will be on the next call.